# 2D physics game engine

Tags: java, game, simulation, physics

I'm writing a 2D game engine, and I just wrote the physics for it to handle collisions between AABBs and circles.

[It's on GitHub.](https://github.com/kyranstar/GameLib)

Some of my worries are that my code isn't OOP, because I have to do a bit of casting. As well as that, the engine doesn't seem to be deterministic, but rather depends on when the update method is called, and I'm not really sure how to fix this (but perhaps that is better asked on Stack Overflow).

This is the main body of my physics code:

```
public final class GamePhysics {
    private GamePhysics() {
        // cant instantiate this class
    }

    public static boolean isColliding(final GameObject a, final GameObject b) {
        if (a instanceof RectObject && b instanceof RectObject) {
            return isColliding((RectObject) a, (RectObject) b);
        }
        if (a instanceof CircleObject && b instanceof CircleObject) {
            return isColliding((CircleObject) a, (CircleObject) b);
        }
        if (a instanceof RectObject && b instanceof CircleObject) {
            return isColliding((RectObject) a, (CircleObject) b);
        }
        if (a instanceof CircleObject && b instanceof RectObject) {
            return isColliding((RectObject) b, (CircleObject) a);
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    private static boolean isColliding(final RectObject a, final RectObject b) {
        final float w = 0.5f * (a.width() + b.width());
        final float h = 0.5f * (a.height() + b.height());
        final float dx = a.center().x - b.center().x;
        final float dy = a.center().y - b.center().y;

        return Math.abs(dx) <= w && Math.abs(dy) <= h;
    }

    private static boolean isColliding(final CircleObject o1, final CircleObject o2) {
        final float c = o1.radius + o2.radius;
        final float b = o1.center.x - o2.center.x;
        final float a = o1.center.y - o2.center.y;

        return c * c > b * b + a * a;
    }

    private static boolean isColliding(final RectObject a, final CircleObject b) {
        final float circleDistance_x = Math.abs(b.center().x - (a.min.x + a.width() / 2));
        final float circleDistance_y = Math.abs(b.center().y - (a.min.y + a.height() / 2));

        if (circleDistance_x > a.width() / 2 + b.radius) {
            return false;
        }
        if (circleDistance_y > a.height() / 2 + b.radius) {
            return false;
        }

        if (circleDistance_x <= a.width() / 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (circleDistance_y <= a.height() / 2) {
            return true;
        }

        final int cornerDistance_sq = (int) Math.pow(circleDistance_x - a.width() / 2, 2) + (int) Math.pow(circleDistance_y - a.height() / 2, 2);

        return cornerDistance_sq <= (int) Math.pow(b.radius, 2);

    }

    private static Vec2D collisionNormal(final RectObject a, final RectObject b) {
        final float w = 0.5f * (a.width() + b.width());
        final float h = 0.5f * (a.height() + b.height());
        final float dx = a.center().x - b.center().x;
        final float dy = a.center().y - b.center().y;

        if (Math.abs(dx) <= w && Math.abs(dy) <= h) {
            /* collision! */
            final float wy = w * dy;
            final float hx = h * dx;

            if (wy > hx) {
                if (wy > -hx) {
                    /* collision at the top */
                    return new Vec2D(0, -1);
                } else {
                    /* on the left */
                    return new Vec2D(1, 0);
                }
            } else {
                if (wy > -hx) {
                    /* on the right */
                    return new Vec2D(-1, 0);
                } else {
                    /* at the bottom */
                    return new Vec2D(0, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rectangles must be colliding");
    }

    public static <A extends GameObject, B extends GameObject> void fixCollision(final A a, final B b) {
        final CollisionManifold<A, B> m = generateManifold(a, b);

        // Calculate relative velocity
        final Vec2D rv = b.velocity.minus(a.velocity);

        // Calculate relative velocity in terms of the normal direction
        final float velAlongNormal = rv.dotProduct(m.normal);

        // Calculate restitution
        final float e = Math.min(a.restitution, b.restitution);

        // Calculate impulse scalar
        float j = -(1 + e) * velAlongNormal;
        j /= a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass();

        // Apply impulse
        final Vec2D impulse = m.normal.multiply(j);
        a.velocity = a.velocity.minus(impulse.multiply(a.getInvMass()));
        b.velocity = b.velocity.plus(impulse.multiply(b.getInvMass()));

        applyFriction(m, j);

        positionalCorrection(m);
    }

    public static <A extends GameObject, B extends GameObject> void applyFriction(final CollisionManifold<A, B> m, final float normalForce) {
        final A a = m.a;
        final B b = m.b;

        // relative velocity
        final Vec2D rv = b.velocity.minus(a.velocity);
        // normalized tangent force
        final Vec2D tangent = rv.minus(m.normal.multiply(m.normal.dotProduct(rv))).unitVector();
        // friction magnitude
        final float jt = -rv.dotProduct(tangent) / (a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass());

        // friction coefficient
        final float mu = (a.staticFriction + b.staticFriction) / 2;
        final float dynamicFriction = (a.dynamicFriction + b.dynamicFriction) / 2;

        // Coulomb's law: force of friction <= force along normal * mu
        final Vec2D frictionImpulse = Math.abs(jt) < normalForce * mu ? tangent.multiply(jt) : tangent.multiply(-normalForce * dynamicFriction);

        a.velocity = a.velocity.minus(frictionImpulse.multiply(a.getInvMass()));
        b.velocity = b.velocity.plus(frictionImpulse.multiply(b.getInvMass()));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <A extends GameObject, B extends GameObject> CollisionManifold<A, B> generateManifold(final A a, final B b) {
        if (a instanceof RectObject && b instanceof RectObject) {
            return (CollisionManifold<A, B>) generateManifold((RectObject) a, (RectObject) b);
        } else if (a instanceof CircleObject && b instanceof CircleObject) {
            return (CollisionManifold<A, B>) generateManifold((CircleObject) a, (CircleObject) b);
        } else if (a instanceof RectObject && b instanceof CircleObject) {
            return (CollisionManifold<A, B>) generateManifold((RectObject) a, (CircleObject) b);
        } else if (a instanceof CircleObject && b instanceof RectObject) {
            return (CollisionManifold<A, B>) generateManifold((RectObject) b, (CircleObject) a);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    private static CollisionManifold<RectObject, RectObject> generateManifold(final RectObject a, final RectObject b) {
        final CollisionManifold<RectObject, RectObject> m = new CollisionManifold<>();

        m.a = a;
        m.b = b;

        final Rectangle2D r = a.toRectangle().createIntersection(b.toRectangle());

        m.normal = collisionNormal(a, b);
        // penetration is the min resolving distance
        m.penetration = (float) Math.min(r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
        return m;
    }

    private static CollisionManifold<CircleObject, CircleObject> generateManifold(final CircleObject a, final CircleObject b) {
        final CollisionManifold<CircleObject, CircleObject> m = new CollisionManifold<>();
        m.a = a;
        m.b = b;

        // A to B
        final Vec2D n = b.center.minus(a.center);
        final float dist = n.length();

        if (dist == 0) {
            // circles are on the same position, choose random but consistent values
            m.normal = new Vec2D(0, 1);
            m.penetration = Math.min(a.radius, b.radius);
            return m;
        }
        // don't recalculate dist to normalize
        m.normal = n.divide(dist);
        m.penetration = b.radius + a.radius - dist;
        return m;
    }

    private static CollisionManifold<RectObject, CircleObject> generateManifold(final RectObject a, final CircleObject b) {
        final CollisionManifold<RectObject, CircleObject> m = new CollisionManifold<>();

        m.a = a;
        m.b = b;
        // Vector from A to B
        final Vec2D n = b.center.minus(a.center());

        // Closest point on A to center of B
        Vec2D closest = n;

        // Calculate half extents along each axis
        final float x_extent = a.width() / 2;
        final float y_extent = a.height() / 2;

        // Clamp point to edges of the AABB
        closest = new Vec2D(clamp(closest.x, -x_extent, x_extent), clamp(closest.y, -y_extent, y_extent));

        boolean inside = false;

        // Circle is inside the AABB, so we need to clamp the circle's center
        // to the closest edge
        if (n.equals(closest)) {
            inside = true;
            // Find closest axis
            if (Math.abs(closest.x) > Math.abs(closest.y)) {
                // Clamp to closest extent
                closest = new Vec2D(closest.x > 0 ? x_extent : -x_extent, closest.y);
            }
            // y axis is shorter
            else {
                // Clamp to closest extent
                closest = new Vec2D(closest.x, closest.y > 0 ? y_extent : -y_extent);
            }
        }
        // closest point to center of the circle
        final Vec2D normal = n.minus(closest);
        final float d = normal.length();
        final float r = b.radius;
        // Collision normal needs to be flipped to point outside if circle was
        // inside the AABB
        m.normal = inside ? normal.unitVector().multiply(-1) : normal.unitVector();
        m.penetration = r - d;
        return m;
    }

    private static float clamp(final float n, final float lower, final float upper) {
        return Math.max(lower, Math.min(n, upper));
    }

    private static <A extends GameObject, B extends GameObject> void positionalCorrection(final CollisionManifold<A, B> m) {
        final A a = m.a;
        final B b = m.b;

        final float percent = .8f; // usually .2 to .8
        final float slop = 0.01f; // usually 0.01 to 0.1
        final Vec2D correction = m.normal.multiply(Math.max(m.penetration - slop, 0.0f) / (a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass()) * percent);
        a.moveRelative(correction.multiply(-1 * a.getInvMass()));
        b.moveRelative(correction.multiply(b.getInvMass()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did a very nice job organizing your code. I especially like how you used operator overloading for collision detection!

---

In your method `collisionNormal`, you have this chunk of code at the beginning:

```
final float w = 0.5f * (a.width() + b.width());
final float h = 0.5f * (a.height() + b.height());
final float dx = a.center().x - b.center().x;
final float dy = a.center().y - b.center().y;

if (Math.abs(dx) <= w && Math.abs(dy) <= h) {
```

Now where have I seen that before... oh right! It looks *exactly* like `isColliding(final RectObject a, final RectObject b)`!

I don't really see the point of writing that code again exactly in this method. I think it'd be a lot easier to just use the `isColliding` method that you already wrote.

---

With things as big and as complicated as physics engines, things can get easily confusing. What if you stopped working on this for a while and then came back to it later? It would be difficult to understand some crucial parts of your code.

To aid this, you should supply your methods and classes, and (optionally) fields with JavaDoc so you can provide as much explanation as needed to understand the code fully.

For example, I am having trouble understanding all the math being done in `applyFriction` and `fixCollision`. With JavaDoc, you could explain what formulas you are following, or what your reasoning is behind whatever you are doing.

---

I'd say you are doing good with keeping your code OO, for what you've written so far.

I recommend looking at pre-existing physics engines for reference on how they organize their data.

For example, some physics engines describe certain forces in objects. As in, friction would be an object that is instantiated with a "power" which is then added to the game and affects object in a way that friction would based on how much "power" was described (some objects are more slippery than others).

Also, there might be an object for describing a moving force, which might have properties describing direction, power, etc.

Some good examples of game engines with physics engines are [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/), [Unreal](https://www.unrealengine.com/), and [ROBLOX Studio](http://www.roblox.com/).

---

I apologize for not giving a more in-depth review. As mentioned, I had trouble understanding the math and why it was being done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'instance of' you are breaking OO and are using a more functional style. Its not terrible. Its just not OO.
Preferably each method should accept its input and not inspect it. The external behaviour of a object should be defined by its type alone.

Several static overloaded 'isColliding', give them real names. You know what method you want, show it.

Adding "Object" to type names suggests a slight confusion in what a Object is in OO/Java. It also has a meaning, no need to overload that word.

Collisions happen between shapes on a plane. Not between GameObjects.
The code should reflect this. A hint here is that some game objects could be made from multiple shapes. Use composition, game objects 'has' collision shapes, not 'is' one.

Adding a virtual circle around AABBs can help simplify the problem. Tests all objects as circles first. Take AABBs for a second round if they collided.

It is useful to test for all collisions at once, instead of one at a time. Speed is at best n^n if you don't, you can do better than that. Sorting the objects per axis can be a nice start.

'static' methods are a good part of OO design. But you could use more interfaces/objects. Hiding your collision code behind a interface will help you compare the speed between different implementations later on. Design the user code first, then put what it need in a interface.

Prefer to add comments as javadoc to methods rather than inline in method comments. Remember that code is a liability, and so is comments.

Best of luck with OO and game programming. Remember that coding your own game engine is heaps of fun. But when you are done you have a game engine, not a game. Decide early what it is that you want.